# Can't understand the purpose of pid->tasks[] list

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm using CentOS7 3.10.0-1160.el7 kernel.

I've added to the kernel the following code to analyze the `pid->tasks` of needed task whenever I want:

```
struct pid *pid = current->pids[PIDTYPE_PGID].pid;
hlist_for_each_entry(task, &pid->tasks[PIDTYPE_PGID], pids[PIDTYPE_PGID].node) {
        char buf_append[128] = {0}; 

        snprintf(buf_append, sizeof(buf_append), " [task:%p|%s|%d|%d]",
                        task, task->comm, task->pid, task->tgid);
        strncat(buf, buf_append, sizeof(buf) - strlen(buf) - 1);
}
```

I've also written a C program that creates few threads that trigger that output from kernel.

When I run the program I get the following debug output:

```
[ 2327.780765] pid: [8856] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2327.790319] pid: [8853] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2327.793864] pid: [8857] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2327.798440] pid: [8854] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2327.803237] pid: [8858] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2327.808940] pid: [8855] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2328.792194] pid: [8856] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2328.797662] pid: [8857] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2328.802301] pid: [8854] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2328.808266] pid: [8858] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
[ 2328.813471] pid: [8855] tgid: [8853] [task:ffff9671b9dc0000|my_prog|8853|8853]
```

- pid/tgid - IDs of a thread that triggers the output

So, you can see that there are several tasks that share the same tgid (8853) but their `pid->tasks[PIDTYPE_PGID]` list contains only one task (group_leader). **Why is that?**

I expect that list should contain all those tasks-thread.

Comment: @0andriy i'm a newbie in linux kernel, could you please clarify what do you mean under children list and where can i find it?

Comment: @0andriy either you are wrong or i don't understand something. hlist is not the list of lists in general, according to [google](http://hejq.me/2014/05/29/lkds-hash-list) it's the list type used for hashtables. &pid->tasks[PIDTYPE_PGID] is the **bucket** that i've iterated already. So my initial question is actual still.